# CheckBoxPreference default vale not working with SharedPreferences before you first open Preference page

Tags: android

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            boolean cbTest = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox_test", false);
```

this are my preference

```
<CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="checkbox_test"
            android:summary="@string/checkbox_tes"
            android:title="@string/title_heckbox_tes" />
```

and `cbTest` variable is by default always false, when I open page with preferences and then check `cbTest` again then is true. Why is by default always false? Why preference page needs to be initialized that start working?

How can I check default value before open preference page?

Answer (score 1):

I already answer similar question but I cannot quickly located. You have to initialize your default share preferences. In your main activity put the code below in onCreate()

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.yourfilename, false);
```

Comment: does not help. It is still false

Comment: That is strange, I can only refer you to this document http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html scroll down to Setting Default Values section.

Comment: last value, PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.yourfilename, true);

Comment: That is strange, I don't think you should call like that because I think it means that your preference would be reset every time. May be you should uninstall your app and run again to see if it works with false. Your data may be cached.